# How to create <text>...</text> node in Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I need to form such xml:

```
<jobs>
  <job>
    <title><![CDATA[cleaner]]></title>
    <description><![CDATA[cleaner in af]]></description>
    <text><![CDATA[cleaner weekly in af]]></text>
    <referencenumber><![CDATA[518]]></referencenumber>
    <company><![CDATA[we q.]]></company>
    <country_code><![CDATA[NL]]></country_code>
    <city><![CDATA[af]]></city>
    <url><![CDATA[url]]></url>
  </job>
</jobs>
```

```
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new(:encoding => 'UTF-8') do |xml|
      xml.jobs {
        data.each do |data|
          xml.job {
            xml.title {
              xml.cdata "..."
            }
            xml.text {
              xml.cdata "..."
        }
    end
   }
 end
```

The above isn't working because `text` is an existing method on builder.

How do I create a `<text>...</text>` node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Builder#label-Special+Tags):

> The builder works by taking advantage of method_missing. Unfortunately some methods are defined in ruby that are difficult or dangerous to remove. You may want to create tags with the name “type”, “class”, and “id” for example. In that case, you can use an underscore to disambiguate your tag name from the method call.

Appending an underscore also works for “text”, i.e. use `text_` instead:

```
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new(:encoding => 'UTF-8') do |xml|
  xml.job {
    xml.text_ {
      xml.cdata 'foo bar baz'
    }
  }
end

puts builder.to_xml
```

Output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<job>
  <text><![CDATA[foo bar baz]]></text>
</job>
```